# Could not drop the last static partition in Oracle table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rdbms, database-partitioning

I have a table with the statically created partitions by range, monthly based:

```
...
PARTITION BY RANGE (expiration_time) INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'month')) (
  PARTITION p_2021_10 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-11-2021', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
  PARTITION p_2021_11 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-12-2021', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
  PARTITION p_2021_12 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-01-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
  PARTITION p_2022_01 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-02-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
  PARTITION p_2022_02 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-03-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))
...
```

After those partitions, the rest of them are dynamically created by ORACLE DBMS:

```
P_2022_02   TIMESTAMP' 2022-03-01 00:00:00' <<< Last statically created partition
SYS_P18684  TIMESTAMP' 2022-04-01 00:00:00' <<< Dynamic partition 1
SYS_P18902  TIMESTAMP' 2022-05-01 00:00:00' <<< Dynamic partition 2
SYS_P19364  TIMESTAMP' 2022-06-01 00:00:00' <<< Dynamic partition 3
...
```

I have a procedure that removes the obsolete partitions, but it fails to drop the last statically created one:

```
ALTER TABLE TRANSACTION_LOG DROP PARTITION p_2022_02 UPDATE INDEXES

Error report -
ORA-14758: Last partition in the range section cannot be dropped
14758. 00000 -  "Last partition in the range section cannot be dropped"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to drop the last range partition of an interval
           partitioned table.
*Action:   Do not attempt to drop this partition.
```

Personally, I see no point why couldn't I remove the last statically created partition, when there are dynamically created partitions afterwards.

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

---

### UPDATE:

I've managed to find a workaround for the issue, since there is no way to have only dynamically created partitions in Oracle. So I've added the criteria in my procedure, so it deletes every partition lower than the current date EXCEPT this remaining statically created partition (**t.partition_name != 'P_2022_02'**):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE REMOVE_OBSOLETE_PARTITIONS IS BEGIN

BEGIN
    DECLARE CURSOR OBSOLETE_PARTITIONS IS
    SELECT PARTITION_NAME FROM (
      SELECT PARTITION_NAME,
            TO_DATE(substr(
                        extractvalue(dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(
                                            'select high_value FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE table_name = '''
                                            || t.table_name || ''' and PARTITION_NAME = '''
                                            || t.partition_name || ''''
                                        ), '//text()'
                        ), 12, 10),
                    'YYYY-MM-DD') AS high_value
      FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS t
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TRANSACTION_LOG' AND t.partition_name != 'P_2022_02')
    WHERE high_value < sysdate;

    BEGIN
        FOR result IN OBSOLETE_PARTITIONS LOOP
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('ALTER TABLE TRANSACTION_LOG DROP PARTITION ' || result.PARTITION_NAME || ' UPDATE INDEXES');
        END LOOP;
    END;
END;

END REMOVE_OBSOLETE_PARTITIONS;
```

If there is a lot of data inside your last static partition, you could truncate it. Anyway, it would be best if you predict creation of one partition to serve as a default one, that will not contain any data and that will be, of course, excluded from your procedure for removal.

Comment: The is about the "transition point", which is mentioned in the documentation. If you have access to My Oracle Support, have a look at [Document 882681.1 (ORA-14758: Last Partition In The Range Section Cannot Be Dropped)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=882681.1) and [Document 1526571.1 (How To Avoid ORA-14758 in Interval Partitioned Table)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1526571.1).

Comment: Hi, Alex, thanks for the answer! However, in the meantime I've found a way and updated the post.